# Is there a R function similar to ifelse but with multiple consequences?

Tags: r

I'm currently trying to analyze some survey data.
Four of my questions give me a headache:
They are closed questions (a, b, c or d =1, 2, 3 or 4)
There is always one correct, two "not too bad" and one completely wrong answer.
Basically all I want to do is to give 1 point for the correct, 0 for the "not really but..." and -1 for the wrong answer.

Pretty sure ifelse won't get me far since the consequences are binary.
I tried to recode but that leads to another problem:
Sometimes answer A is correct and B is completely false, other times C is the good one and D is wrong etc.

So I cant just use something like this:

```
Data <- apply(Data, 2, function(x) {x <- recode(x,"1=0; 2=-1; 3=0; 4=1"); x})
```

Since I only got 4 questions, I would recode them one by one but I don't know hot to do so
(Always get an error when I try something like Data§Question1)

> Error in apply(Data$Question1, 2, drop = F, function(x) { : 
>     dim(X) must have a positive length

Comment: Have you tried nested `ifelse`? Could you add some sample data?

Comment: Have a look at `dplyr::case_when`, or `switch`

Comment: Those two options could work fine but my biggest problem is, that the values of what it correct and what not change with each question. Lets say Question 1 has a correct answer value of 1 and a false of 3 but question 2 got it vice versa...

Also, this could provide some example data:

Questions <- c('Question 1','Question 2','Question 3', 'Question 4')
participant_1 <- c(1, 3, 1, 4)
participant_2 <- c(2, 4, 4, 1)
ExampleData <- rbind(Questions,participant_1, participant_2)

Comment: You need to melt/gather/pivot_wider your data first for better control then map case_when/nested_ifelse or whichever other function.

Comment: @EarlGrey. You should NOT use comments to clarify your question. Instead use [edit].

Answer (score 0):

Think of your calculation as involving two steps.  First you find the scoring for a particular question, then you apply that scoring to your data.

We don't have a reproducible example showing us the original form of your data, but here's a general way to approach your problem.

```
# Record the scoring for each question
scoring <- list(Question1 = c(1, 0, -1, 0),
                Question2 = c(-1, 0, 1, 0),
                Question3 = ...)

# Loop through the questions:
for (question in paste0(Question, 1:4)) {
  score <- scoring[[question]]
  answers <- Data[[question]]
  scores <- score[answers]
  # record those scores somewhere
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Questions to SO should have reproducible code and data.  Since there was no data provided in the question I have provided a sample data frame `Data` in the Note at the end.  If your data differs from that make the appropriate modifications.

We also define, in the Note, an input data frame `Codes` such that `Codes[i, j]` is the code -1, 0 or 1 to use for answer equal to i on question j.

Since the answers are represented as 1, 2, 3, 4 in `Data` we can use indexing into `Codes` to lookup the output code corresponding to each answer.

```
cbind( Data[1], mapply(function(x, codes) codes[x], Data[-1], Codes))
```

giving this data frame:

```
  Person Q1 Q2
1      A  0  1
2      B  1  0
3      C  0 -1
4      D -1  0
5      E  0  1
6      F  1  0
7      G  0 -1
8      H -1  0
```

### Note

Input data assumed:

```
Data <- data.frame(Person = LETTERS[1:8], Q1 = 1:4, Q2 = 4:1, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# if, on Q1, the answer is 1 then use 0, if it is 2 use 1, etc.
Codes <- data.frame(Q1 = c(0, 1, 0, -1), Q2 =  c(0, -1, 0, 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the switch() function: https://www.datamentor.io/r-programming/switch-function/#targetText=The%20switch()%20function%20in,the%20corresponding%20value%20is%20returned.

You could do something like this:

```
PointsSum = PointsSum - switch(AnswerID,CorrectAnswerID = 1, NeutralAnswerID = 0, BadAnswerID = -1)
```